# How to integrate the primefaces-extensions CustomExporterFactory into my project with spring-security?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, spring-security, primefaces-extensions

I'm trying to integrate the primefaces-extensions showcase into my project. That is spring security integrated with the primefaces showcase.

This problem exists since adding https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/showcase/util/CustomExporterFactory.java to my project.

I have no clue, what's happening here. When I clean and build my project with `<mojarra.version>2.2.8</mojarra.version>`, it fails with:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project jsfsecure_copy: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERObjectIdentifier not found -> [Help 1]
```

Complete output is here: http://pastebin.com/JVDGhrHb

When I clean and build with `<mojarra.version>2.2.7</mojarra.version>`, it fails with:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project jsfsecure_copy: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.jaxen.FunctionContext not found -> [Help 1]
```

Then I build with `<mojarra.version>2.2.8</mojarra.version>` and without cleaning the project:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project jsfsecure_copy: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.jaxen.FunctionContext not found -> [Help 1]
```

Then I build again with `<mojarra.version>2.2.7</mojarra.version>` and again I do not clean before:

```
BUILD SUCCESS
```

this time!

Please point me to the place I have to look at to solve this issue.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>master-pom</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.wctc.maven.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsfsecure_copy</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>jsfsecure_copy</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.1</aspectj.version>
        <primefaces-extensions.version>3.0.0</primefaces-extensions.version>


        <primefaces-extensions.core.version>3.0.0</primefaces-extensions.core.version>
        <primefaces-extensions.new-components>analogClock;gravatar;documentViewer;gChart;knob;timer</primefaces-extensions.new-components>
        <primefaces-extensions.updated-components>;</primefaces-extensions.updated-components>

        <mojarra.version>2.2.7</mojarra.version>
        <myfaces.version>2.2.4</myfaces.version>

        <jsfVersion>Mojarra-2.2.7</jsfVersion>
        <primefacesVersion>PrimeFaces-5.1</primefacesVersion>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google Guava utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>16.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Superior, open-source Date/Time API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Spring Security Basic Libraries
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            acl
        -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>facelets-taglib-jsf20-spring-3</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Core Spring utilities used by other modules.
            Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Expression Language (depends on spring-core)
            Define this if you use Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core)
            Define this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, spring-beans)
            Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, spring-beans)
            This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection Container and is generally always defined
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, Quartz, and Freemarker integration
            Define this if you need any of these integrations
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-aop, spring-context)
            Define this if you use Spring Transactions or DAO Exception Hierarchy
            (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
            Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, and iBatis.
            (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
            Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans.
            (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
            Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and Portlet Environments
            (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
            Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <!--<version>${junit.version}</version>-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
            Adds extra features for JUnit semantics
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Needed by Logback and Spring to replace commons logging & log4j
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Useful utilities from Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need by Performance Intercepter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Data Exporter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <!--<version>2.1.7</version>-->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- File Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- FeedReader -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>rome</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Twitter API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Atmosphere -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Themes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <!--<version>1.0.10</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- GraphicImage -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
            <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
            <version>1.5-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Barcode -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j-light</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java API's -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- EL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
            <artifactId>juel-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
            <artifactId>juel-spi</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces-extensions.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces-extensions.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-codemirror</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces-extensions.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.security.taglibs.facelets</id>
            <name>SpringSource Security Taglibs</name>
            <url>http://spring-security-facelets-taglib.googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp</webappDirectory>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warSourceExcludes>**/resources/**/*.css,**/resources/**/*.js</warSourceExcludes>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/webapp-resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <packagingExcludes>**/web-overwrite.xml,WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                    <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpeg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>gif</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>bmp</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jar</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>cab</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <X-Compile-Source>${java.version.source}</X-Compile-Source>
                            <X-Compile-Target>${java.version.target}</X-Compile-Target>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp-resources/resources</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.css</include>
                                        <include>**/*.js</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-java-files</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
                <artifactId>resources-optimizer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <resourcesSets>
                        <resourcesSet>
                            <inputDir>${project.build.directory}/webapp-resources</inputDir>
                        </resourcesSet>
                    </resourcesSets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>myfaces</id>
            <properties>
                <jsf-impl>myfaces</jsf-impl>
                <jsf-version>${myfaces.version}</jsf-version>
                <jsf-listener>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</jsf-listener>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${myfaces.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>${myfaces.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mojarra</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <jsf-impl>mojarra</jsf-impl>
                <jsf-version>${mojarra.version}</jsf-version>
                <jsf-listener>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</jsf-listener>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${mojarra.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>${mojarra.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with this? https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204653

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it's that these lines cause the trouble:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Deleting them seems to solve the issue.